# connect to ssh using putty without internet access

Tags: ssh, internet, putty

my raspberry pi has no internet access and I am trying to connect to it using putty's ssh feature.
how can I do it?

Comment: There are already a few dozen questions dealing with networking problems. This question doesn't have enough detail to be answerable. Can you detail exactly what system you're running, what you've tried and what happened when that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a wireless router, network switch, or a cross-over Ethernet cable
I will give you the break-down of the router

1. Hook-up via ethernet cables pi-to-router and pc-to-router (or via PC wireless connection to router).
2. Find the "setting configure address" on a sticker on the router (should look like "http://192.168.X.XXX"); If not on sticker find with an easy command on cmd or terminal. On the PC, open a web browser and enter this Address.
3. There should be a list of connect devices somewhere on this router page (May need additional details from sticker for logging into the router). Find where it says "raspberrypi" and use the ip address given to it in puttys "Host name" box.
4. After hitting connect, there should be a certificate pop-up, select "ok". username is "pi" and password is usually "raspberry".

a cross-over ethernet cord is one where two wires are switched when compare to a traditional ethernet cord; rx and tx. Youcan easily make one and hook the pi straight up to your PC. You will have to make a bridge connection on your network settings. We use to do this with our Gaming Consoles back in the 00s.

if confuse, there are tons of videos on youtube on how to do All of these

Comment: Happily, with the pi, you don't need a crossover cable. Any standard Ethernet cable will do the job just fine.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great thing to know. Did not look into detail about the pi's ethernets Rx & Tx but it would make perfect sense why they would make them both transceivers.